# How to take fulllength screenshot not only the visible area in android real devices by using appium, python and selenium webdriver?

Tags: android, python, selenium, appium

I am trying to get full length screenshot for my webpage which is responsive .I am able to get the screenshot only visible part.Is there any chance to get the screenshot which is visible by scrolling down.I am using python,selenium webdriver and appium.Below is my code

```
desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '4.3'
desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'galaxy s3'
desired_caps['browserName']='Chrome'
self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
self.driver.get('http://www.google.com/');(not exactly this url)
self.driver.implicitly_wait(30);
self.driver.save_screenshot('mobile_app.png')
```